# Excel VBA to copy unique values duplicate 1st value

Tags: vba, excel

I have this excel VBA code

```
Sub Module()

Range("A1:A10").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("D1"), Unique:=True

End Sub
```

I expect it to grab all unique values from column A and dump them in column D

However, the value in D1 is a duplicate.

[image]

Why is this and how do I fix?

Comment: Advanced Filter requires a heading. It assumes the first A in A1 is a header and will automatically copy it across.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach, which doesn't require a header.

```
Sub Module()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Range("A1:A10")
    .Copy .Offset(, 3)
    .Offset(, 3).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert another cell above cell A1. Write "Header" or any other text in this box. Change the range to A1:A11. This should solve your problem.